# SUMX in DAX (PowerBi) isn´t working as supposed to

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently working on a PVM Analysis and everything was running smoothly. Until one of my measures fails to work.
Both measures are practically the same:

One that works:

Novo =

VAR Novo =  FILTER( CODITEM,
[Revenue LY]+0=0)
return

SUMX(Novo, [Revenue TY])

The failed one:
Discontinued =

VAR Discontinued = FILTER(CODITEM,
[Revenue TY]+0=0)
return

SUMX(Discontinued,-[Revenue LY])

Both have to iterate into the "CODITEM" level. One only brings value when revenue LY = 0 and the other when revenue TY = 0.

Other measures here.
Revenue TY = sum(TotalFat)
Revenue LY = CALCULATE([Revenue TY],PREVIOUSMONTH('Date'[Date]))

In my BI filter the page by this month (so that I can see this month revenue in Revenue TY and last month revenue in Revenue LY).

I also attached the data and PBIX file in the link below:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17ZJ3YwwiIaNJitIFNeaOLWNTap792ubc?usp=sharing

I can´t figure it out what this could it be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your formula. When I look at your data, I see that you are filtering the base1[quantfat] column for any Codeitem quantities that are equal to 0, and then pulling any associated revenue from those items.

However, when I look at your base1 table, I can see there are no entries where unit sales are equal to=0, therefore there is no associated revenue for items with zero [quantfat] which is why I think the measure is showing up blank.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, Thank you for your response. I´ve tried to change my code to:
VAR discontinued =  
FILTER(
    Cliente_Produto, 
            [Units TY]+0=0 || ISBLANK([Units TY])
)
return
SUMX(Discontinued,-[Revenue LY])

But still nothing. Any idea on how can I fix it?